# modify keys of a hash using for loop

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I've got 2 dim array and a hash!
Array's second row values and hash keys are set identical!

What I want is to address each hash key using array's row values and change them to array's current column index

Preview example:

```
{.....,'_11':val, '_12':value, .....}
```

`arr[1][i]='_12'`. use this value to address the the unique hash hey and change that key to i. key=i

Is this the right way?

```
var keyName;
for(var i=0; i<theLength; i++){
   keyName = arr[1][i];
   hash.keyName=i;
}
```

10x for your kind help ,BR

Comment: Can you show some example data, and what you want it to look like after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you want is this:

```
var keyName;
for(var i=0; i<theLength; i++) {
  keyName = arr[1][i];
  hash[keyName] = i;
}
```

Using `hash.keyName` will always reference a key called `keyName`, not the key with that variable name.

Since you don't really need the intermediate variable, you can do this:

```
for(var i=0; i<theLength; i++) {
  hash[arr[1][i]] = i;
}
```

Comment: Would you give me an example how to modify key and how to modify value in hash, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: {'city' : 'New York'}

How can be 'city' modified?

Comment: You'd have to remove the `city` key and add a new one under a different name. `delete hash['city']` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I follow what you're asking for the rest, but

```
hash.keyName=i;
```

should be:

```
hash[keyName]=i;
```